# Navigate from UIView to UIViewController without storyboard and navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to navigate from a `UIView`, which is part of a `UIViewController`, to another `UIViewController` neither using storyboards nor navigation controllers?

I have a UITapGestureRecognizer which I want to navigate to another `UIViewController` (`BuyController()`) whenever it is tapped once.  Accordingly, my code looks like this:

```
//handle singleTap
func singleTapOnLikesDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("check") //works
    let toController = BuyController()
    BarController().pushViewController(toController, animated: true) //error occurs since BarController is no navigationcontroller

}
```

`BarController` (`UITabBarController`, `UITabBarControllerDelegate`) is my rootViewController in the `AppDelegate.swift`. The `UIView` however belongs to another `UIViewController` called `HomeController` (`UIViewController`, `UIScrollViewDelegate`). I do not use storyboards at all and I would like to keep it that way, as I am going to work on a project in a team (thus, a programmatic solution would be very welcome)...

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this to navigate, without using `navigationController`:

```
self.present(toController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or Use this,

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(toController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I get an error saying `Value of type 'CurrentClass' [self] has no member presentViewController.` `presentViewController` seems to have been replaced by `present`. Nevertheless, I get the same error... If I replace `self` with `HomeController()`, I get the error `Attempt to present <project.BuyController: 0xBLA> on <project.HomeController: 0xBLA> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: did you add this `func singleTapOnLikesDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) ` in  `UIVIEW` subclass

Answer (score 1):

Only UIViewControllers can present other UIViewControllers not UIViews so your won't find the present method on the UIView.  You also can't replace self with HomeController() because that creates a new HomeController with it's own UIView which hasn't been added to any other view (as the error suggests).

You have a couple of options really:

1) Create a protocol/delegate on your UIView and make the HomeController conform to it.  Then the UIView can call the method in the protocol and the HomeController do the actual switching.

2) You could get the root view controller to present the new UIViewController like this: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`